# SQL Ignore non matching columns

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, db2

I'm trying to develop a stored procedure which does a select on a table. The stored procedure has 4 inputs: Input1, Input2, Input3, Input4.

Table has 4 columns: Col1,Col2,Col3, Col4.

The requirement is if there is no match on all selects, we need to ignore that and select pick next one:

Use case:

```
Select * 
from table 
where Col1=Input1 
  and Col2=Input2 
  and Col3=Input3 
  and Col4=Input4;
```

If there are no returns for the condition due to Col2 not equal to Input2, select needs to ignore it and try to match on others like:

```
Select * 
from table 
where Col1=Input1 
  and Col3=Input3 
  and Col4=Input4;
```

It should go like that till last possible option for the response:

```
Select * 
from table 
where Col1=Input1;
```

Please assist if there is a way and thanks in advance.

Comment: Even if you restricted your question to a single RDBMS, it would still be too broad.

Comment: Please specify your DMS - it cannot be Db2 and MYSQL. You have not provided enough details of the required logic - the way you describe it you could do a simple Col1=Input1 OR Col2 = Imput2 OR Col3=Input3 OR Col4=Input4 in ther WHERE condition.

Comment: I removed the conflicting DBMS tags. Please add only one tag for the database product you are really using.

Comment: Why isn't the last option all the rows in the table?  The question is unclear.  In addition to including the database, you should show an example of what you want for the combinations.  And what to do when different sets of parameters return rows.

Comment: @MichaelTiefenbacher The database is DB2. The issue with OR condition is want to match on as many conditions possible. For example, If there is a record matched on all 4 conditions, we would like to use that. Otherwise, Need to know on what columns it didn't match and try others. Do this until last possible option by priority. Here is the example:

Query: Col1+ Col2 + Col3 + Col4 + Col5


Query: Col1 + Col2 + Col3 + Col4


Query: Col1 + Col2 + Col3



Query: Col1 + Col2 


Query: Col1


Query: Default

Comment: @GordonLinoff The procedure should return and quit when it finds a match on given conditions. Here is the example:

 Query: Col1+ Col2 + Col3 + Col4 + Col5 Query: Col1 + Col2 + Col3 + Col4 Query: Col1 + Col2 + Col3 Query: Col1 + Col2 Query: Col1 Query: Default

Answer (score 0):

As it's mentioned in the comments, the question is a bit vague so I'm afraid any answer would be a bit vague too. You could do something like this:

```
select top 1 *,
case when Coll=input1 then 1 else 0 end as match1,
case when Col2=input2 then 1 else 0 end as match2,
case when Col3=input3 then 1 else 0 end as match3,
case when Col4=input4 then 1 else 0 end as match4
from table
order by match1+match2+match3+match4 desc
```

this is assuming SQL server as the DBMS (if it is Oracle, you may need to use LIMIT instead of TOP, for instance)  and I also assumed that the columns have all the same weight in terms of matching.
Also, I'm assuming that you want only one of the best matches, if not you may need to do some changes to the TOP and/or use a where clause.
Finally, You may want to use isnull() if your columns and/or inputs are nullable.

Comment: This logic doesn't work if the query is expected to return more than one row.  But it is a clever interpretation of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm . . . One method is:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when condition1 then 1 else 0 end) over () as c_1,
             sum(case when condition1 and condition2 then 1 else 0 end) over () as c_12,
             sum(case when condition1 and condition2 and condition3 then 1 else 0 end) over () as c_123,
             sum(case when condition1 and condition2 and condition3 and condition4 then 1 else 0 end) over () as c_1234
      from t
     ) t
where (c_1234 > 0 and condition1 and condition2 and condition3 and condition4) or
      (c_1234 = 0 and c_123 > 0 and condition1 and condition2 and condition3) and
      (c_123 = 0 and c_12 > 0 and condition1 and condition2 ) and
      (c_12 = 0 and c_1 > 0 and condition1 ) ;
```

Depending on the conditions and other considerations -- such as whether you only expect one row -- there might be simpler methods.